# Add external plugin to sonarqube

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I'm running sonarqube in a docker container using this compose docker file:
[docker-compose](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md)

I want to add an external plugin (jar file). I couldn't manage to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: You can follow the structure of your referenced docker-compose file and bind it to your container through a volume.

Comment: Since i'm very new to docker, still do not know how to do that.

Comment: Okay. So you want to add a jar to your service "sonarqube", yes? Where do you want to store it inside of this service (i.e. what should be the path to your jar in the container)?

Comment: The path is: SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy your jars to your local folder "sonarqube_extensions/plugins" which should exist next to your docker-compose.yml file and they will be linked into your container according to your referenced docker-compose.yml file.

**Old answer**

You can modify your existing docker-compose.yml file. Assuming your jar files are located in a folder named "external_jars" next to the compose file and you want these jars to be available inside the container under, for example, `/opt/sonarqube/external_jars` (I am not familiar with sonarQube and I do not know how the correct structure should look like). Then you can add one line to this excerpt of your compose file:

```
sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
    volumes:
      - external_jars:/opt/sonarqube/external_jars  # <-- Added this line
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins
```

Or you just add the jars locally into the folder "sonarqube_extensions" if this is the correct folder. I do not know what you want to achieve, therefore I can only guess what you are trying.

"Volumes" are linked folders between your local machine (which is running the docker engine) and the container. The syntax "sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions" means: map the contents of "sonarqube_extensions" of the *local* machine to the container and make it accessible at the path "/opt/sonarqube/extensions".

Comment: Thanks @n2o. That worked. A precision though: the local folder "sonarqube_extensions" is created in /var/lib/docker